# issues with CGI::Minimal

Tags: perl, cgi

My existing code works fine with vanilla cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session;

my ( $session, $cgi);

$cgi = new CGI();
$cgi->charset('UTF-8');

$session = new CGI::Session( "driver:File;serializer:Storable",
    $cgi, { Directory => '../home/tmp' } );
$session->expire( 'authorized', '1440m' );
```

changing over to CGI::Minimal causes CGI::Session to error out

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use CGI::Minimal;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session;

my ( $session,  $cgi);

my $cgi = CGI::Minimal->new;

$session = new CGI::Session( "driver:File;serializer:Storable",
    $cgi, { Directory => '../web/tmp' } ) or or die CGI::Session->errstr();
$session->expire( 'authorized', '1440m' );
```

The error

```
Can't call method "expire" on an undefined value at /var/webserver/iris/htdocs/index.cgi line 13.
```

Edit: after  `or die CGI::Session->errstr()` is added

```
new(): failed: query object CGI::Minimal=HASH(0x9916a64) does not support cookie() and param() methods:
```

Not really sure what causes this, really appreciate any insight.

Comment: Sure it works? You are nor declaring `$cgi` but you have `use strict`. That will break. Please don't type code in here, copy it from your editor or IDE. [Edit] your question and fix that please.

Comment: It's very possible that CGI::Session doesn't like the CGI::Minimal object because the interface it expects is not satisfied. Add a `or die` to the `CGI::Seession->new` to see if it returns `undef`.

Comment: Also: turn on `warnings`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#new), `CGI::Session::new` calls the passed CGI object's `cookie` method; CGI::Minimal [doesn't appear to have a `cookie` method](https://metacpan.org/source/SNOWHARE/CGI-Minimal-1.29/lib/CGI/Minimal.pm), so that could be throwing it off, although that's just a guess. Add `or die CGI::Session->errstr();` after your call to `CGI::Session::new` to find the exact reason.

Comment: ok i cleaned it up, @simbabque, yeah so is CGI::Minimal not compatible with CGI::Session?

Comment: Well, your answer is right in the error message: "CGI::Minimal...does not support cookie() and param() methods"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot that appears to be the issue, so I need to use another session module essentially, or is this another way around this?

Comment: You don't *have* to pass a CGI object to `CGI::Session::new`. You can also pass a session ID, or no arguments at all. See the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#new).

Comment: yeah I guess I am going to rewrite my existing code, thanks for all the help

Comment: But how would handling the session id work without cookies?

Comment: @simbabque You can still send cookies with CGI::Minimal. The module is, after all, just a fancy frontend to HTTP requests. The docs even mention using CGI::Cookie.

Comment: @this I didn't read the docs. Was on mobile. Just wanted to pose the question so OP is aware of the fact that there might be a caveat. :)

Comment: "or or die " is is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Since CGI::Minimal is indeed rather minimal you'd have to handle Cookies yourself and pass the manually retrieved session_id, instead of the cgi object, to the CGI::Session constructor.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI::Cookie;
use CGI::Minimal;

use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser/;
use CGI::Session;

my $cgi = CGI::Minimal->new();

my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;

my $session_id;

if( defined $cookies{'SESSION_ID'} ){
   $session_id = $cookies{'SESSION_ID'}->value;
}

my $session = CGI::Session->new(
  "driver:File;serializer:Storable",
  $session_id,
  { Directory => '../web/tmp' }
  ) or die CGI::Session->errstr();

$session->expire( 'authorized', '1440m' );

my $session_cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name => 'SESSION_ID',-value => $session->id());

print $session->header(-cookie=>[$session_cookie]);

print 'ok with session_id: ' . $session->id();
```